# Overriding getReviewsCollection() in core/Review/Block/Product/View.php does not work as expected

Tags: magento

I needed to edit the `getReviewsCollection()` function to include related products.

Putting a copy of View.php in `app/code/local/Mage/Review/Block/Product` with the edited `getReviewsCollection()` function worked just as expected. All of the related products' reviews showed up on the product review page (in the "review/product_view_list" block).

So because it seemed to work the way I wanted, I tried to create an extension instead of doing the `local/Mage` thing. I put it in `app/code/local/Example/Review`. I put an Example_Review.xml file in `etc/modules`. I put a config.xml in `app/code/local/Example/Review/etc`.

The config.xml looked something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Example_Review>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Example_Review>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <blocks>
      <review>
        <rewrite>
          <product_view>Example_Review_Block_Product_View</product_view>
        </rewrite>
      </review>
    </blocks>
  </global>
</config>
```

View.php looked like this:

```
class Example_Review_Block_Product_View extends Mage_Review_Block_Product_View
  {
  ...
  }
```

It no longer worked like it did in the `local/Mage` case. It seemed like the old, original getReviewsCollection() function was being used inside the "review/product_list" block. I confirmed my suspicions by inserting the following in `app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/review/product/view/list.phtml`:

> echo $this->getReviewsCollection()->getSelect();

The mysql query given by that matched the original `getReviewsCollection()` - not the new, edited one in Example_Review_Block_Product_View. Furthermore, putting the

> echo $this->getReviewsCollection()->getSelect();

line in `app/design/frontend/default/theme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` gave a different mysql query that matched the new, edited `getReviewsCollection()`.

To sum up, the problem is that Magento is using the edited `getReviewCollection()` in the 'review/Product_View' block, but at the same time using the original `getReviewCollection()` in the 'review/Product_View_List' block. Why? Why does putting it in `local/Mage` avoid this problem?

I got around it by putting a copy of List.php in `app/code/local/Mage/Review/Block/Product/View` with an exact copy of the edited `getReviewsCollection()` function added on (while also adding the rewrite to config.xml). It works, but it seems like a stupid way to do things.

Again, what am I missing? There must be something I don't quite understand about overriding blocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like it's a little bit late to answer, let me continue however.

This is to happen, and should you blame someone, it should go to architecture.

> If you take a look at : app/code/core/Mage/Review/Block/Product/View/List.php

**please take a note on parent class which the class extends from.*

```
class Mage_Review_Block_Product_View_List extends Mage_Review_Block_Product_View
{ 
    protected $_forceHasOptions = false;

    public function getProductId()
    {
        return Mage::registry('product')->getId();
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        if ($toolbar = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_review_list.toolbar')) {
            $toolbar->setCollection($this->getReviewsCollection());
            $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->getReviewsCollection()
            ->load()
            ->addRateVotes();
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    public function getReviewUrl($id)
    {
        return Mage::getUrl('review/product/view', array('id' => $id));
    }
}
```

Did you notice this part of the code :

```
$toolbar->setCollection($this->getReviewsCollection());
```

While they extend from Mage_Review_Block_Product_View?

That's why even if you overwrite Mage_Review_Block_Product_View, still getReviewsCollection method of the Mage core View.php class will be used instead of yours.

**Solution : You need to overwrite List.php class as well.**

> config.xml

```
    <blocks>
        <review>
            <rewrite>
                <product_view>Namespace_Extension_Block_Product_View</product_view>
                <product_view_list>Namespace_Extension_Block_Product_View_List</product_view_list>
            </rewrite>
        </review>
    </blocks>
```

> Namespace_Extension_Block_Product_View_List.php

```
class Namespace_Extension_Block_Product_View_List extends Namespace_Extension_Block_Product_View
{

    protected $_forceHasOptions = false;

    public function getProductId()
    {
        return Mage::registry('product')->getId();
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        if ($toolbar = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product_review_list.toolbar')) {
            $toolbar->setCollection($this->getReviewsCollection());
            $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->getReviewsCollection()
            ->load()
            ->addRateVotes();
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    public function getReviewUrl($id)
    {
        return Mage::getUrl('review/product/view', array('id' => $id));
    }
}
```

Now, your modified View.php and its getReviewsCollection method should work as you make a change to it.

Comment: Does this hold true for magento 2 as well ? I'm facing similar issue in magento 2.